# Vehicle Detection and Tracking unisng Lucas kanade

Tags: image-processing, tracking, detection

I have an image processing project, clearly the title reveals what it is.

Assume I have a camera on top of the one of the traffic lights beside a four way in a heavy crowded city. The project should get the recorded video from that camera.
Identify the cars on the scene and track their movements.

for the tracking part I believe Lucas Kanade with pyramids or even Lucas Kanade Tomasi would be sufficient.

But before tracking I should Identify the cars coming into the scene. I wonder how I can do that. I mean how I can distinguish between people/trees/building/... and cars.

what should I do for identifying ?
I want you to be kind enough with me and share your ideas.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected contours and filtered them by size. That worked for me using the same video available on the link posted by GiLevi (http://www.behance.net/gallery/Vehicle-Detection-Tracking-and-Counting/4057777).  You could also perform background sutraction, and detect blobs, on the foreground mask; again filtering by size, so as to differentiate from cars, people etc.

Comment: Were you able to use Lucas Kanade to track the cars through?

Comment: I used LK for other problems and for this one, I'm going to use.

Comment: Ok. I just tried using LK, and was able to track the bounding boxes.